# C Programming IEEE 754 decimal to binary converter

Tags: c

I'm very new to C, I was trying to understand this code but there are some things I don't understand, for example the argument `Byte data[]` and I don't get what is passed to the function by giving it `(Byte *) &i`.
I'd appreciate any help possible, thanks.

Code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>

typedef unsigned char Byte;

void showsignal(char str[], Byte data[], int size) {
    int i,j;

    printf ("%s: ", str);
    for (i = size-1; i> size-2; i--) {
        for (j = 1; j > 0; j--) {
            int bit = (data[i] >> j) & 1;
            printf ("%d", bit);
        }
    }
    printf ("n");
}

void showexponent(char str[], Byte data[], int size) {
    int i,j;

    printf ("%s: ", str);
    for (i = size-2; i>size-3; i--) {
        for (j = 7; j >= 0; j--) {
            int bit = (data[i] >> j) & 1;
            printf ("%d", bit);
        }
    }
    printf ("n");
}

void showsignificand(char str[], Byte data[], int size) {
    int i,j;

    printf ("%s: ", str);
    for (i = size-3; i>size-4 ; i--) {
        for (j = 23; j > 0; j--) {
            int bit = (data[i] >> j) & 1;
            printf ("%d", bit);
        }
    }
    printf ("n");
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
   float f;
   int i;

   f = atof(argv[1]);
   i = trunc(f);
   if (f-i == 0) {
       showsignal("sinal", (Byte *) &i, sizeof(i));
       showexponent("expoente", (Byte *) &i, sizeof(i));
       showsignificand("mantissa", (Byte *) &i, sizeof(i));
   } else {
       showsignal("sinal", (Byte *) &f, sizeof(f));
       showexponent("expoente", (Byte *) &f, sizeof(f));
       showsignificand("mantissa", (Byte *) &f, sizeof(f));
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please can you include the pastebin code directly in the question?

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
showsignal("signal", (Byte *) &i, sizeof(i));
```

means we call the function showsignal and pass it 3 arguments.

The first argument is an the string "signal", that's simple.

The second argument is a bit more complicated. The &i gets you the address of the variable i and then we cast that address to a Byte pointer. Because the function expects a pointer to a Byte we can't just send it the address of an integer. That's why we got to cast it to a Byte pointer.

Answer (score 0):

This function takes the argument you queried, `Byte data[]`, which is a pointer to an array of unsigned char:

```
void showsignal(char str[], Byte data[], int size) {
```

It displays the array in binary and is called from `main()` like this:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    float f;
    int i;
    f = atof(argv[1]);
    i = trunc(f);
    if (f-i == 0) {
        showsignal("sinal", (Byte *) &i, sizeof(i));
```

The code inputs a number `float f` and converts it to `int i`. It then passes the `int` to the function by casting it to appear as an array of unsigned bytes. The function then prints it in binary. It knows the length of the array it is passed because of the `sizeof(i)` which is the number of bytes of `i`.

The cast in needed because the compiler will not accept `int` for the argument `unsigned char*`. So the program writer took the address of the `int` with `&i`, cast it to `unsigned char*` pointer using `(Byte *) &i`, then the function can treat it as an array to print in binary bits.